# Textwidth underline while ragged right text

Tags: ulem

I want to do this:

[image]

But all I can do is:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\begin{document}
\hfill\begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft}
Lorem:~\uline{ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam 
nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed 
diam voluptua.\hfill}
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I fill ragged side with empty underlines?

Answer (score 1):

I have found solution with kindly help of Donald Arseneau, author of `ulem` package. So here it is:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\newcommand\s{\nobreak \hskip\fill \allowbreak \space \hskip-\fill \relax}

\begin{document}
\hfill\begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\textwidth}
 \begin{flushleft}
 \obeyspaces\let =\s
 Lorem:~\uline{ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.\hfill}
 \end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

and here is result:
[image]

but when I try to write environment like this

```
\newenvironment{under}
{\obeyspaces\let =\s}
{}

\begin{document}
\hfill\begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\textwidth}
 \begin{flushleft}
 \begin{under}
Lorem:~\uline{ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.\hfill}
 \end{under}
 \end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

there is an error appearing

`! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 
l.13 \begin{under}`

Why?